# Is it rude to tell someone "I need to talk to you about this paper"

Tags: formality

Today I wrote this sentence to my supervisor who is a native speaker of English:

> I need to talk to you about this paper.

Now I am worried this could be rude. Would you say this is rude, or not?

Comment: Elaborate, please, as to why do _you_ think it could be rude.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many native speakers feel that there's a difference between "talk **to**" and "talk **with**": the former is used when talking down (parent to child, supervisor to employee, etc.) and the latter when talking up (student to teacher, etc.) or when talking to peers (friends). A few of the native speaker users here expressed this opinion in answers to a question here about two weeks ago.

I would recommend that you respect this distinction if only on the theory that you don't know who might take offense: better safe than sorry.

You should have said "I **would like** to talk **with** you about this paper **if you have some free time this week or next**". *Would like* is more polite and less imperious than *I need to*, and the final conditional clause puts your relationship into the proper perspective: you're **asking** your superior (your immediate boss) for his or her time, so it has to be at your boss's convenience. *I need to* sounds too urgent and is more like a command than a request.

Register is always important because many times it's more important **how you say something** than what you say.

Perhaps your supervisor shares cytpe.h's opinion that it's not rude, but perhaps not. I don't feel a difference, but because I know that so many native Anglophones do, I'm always aware of how I say it: with **to** or with **with**. I don't want to ruffle feathers for no reason.

Comment: I'd agree with this assessment. It's not so much that the original wording is "rude," but it's not quite as courteous as it could be.

Comment: I too agree. Phrases such as "we need to talk" declare an intention to offer corrective counsel.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for your supervisor, but I wouldn't consider it rude. However, this sentence might convey a no-nonsense, down-to-business attitude. If you say it too often, he may think you are being pesky, but that would most likely be because of frequency of use, not the sentence itself. I would also be sure to thank him for his time.