# Pronoun use with preposition: "with *he* and his wife" or "with *him* and his wife"?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, case

This sentence was in a newspaper article: 
"Eddie smiled as Will talked with he and his wife."

I feel it means "Eddie smiled as Will talked (with him) and (with his wife)."

So it should be "Eddie smiled as Will talked with him and his wife.

Which one is correct?

Comment: You are correct.The newspaper needs a new copy editor.

Comment: "Him" is correct because the object, not the subject pronoun is needed here (as it is the object of the preposition "with").

Comment: Related: [Which version is correct and normally used, “between you and me” or “between you and I”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/58531/3281)

Comment: Eddie smiled as Will talked to him and his wife.

Comment: In some dialects it's grammatical to say *"Eddie smiled as Will talked with **he and his wife**"*. But it's not considered correct in Standard English. If we substitute the coordination, and replace it with a single pronoun, we see that an accusative form is proper (for example *"them"*). So the correct Standard English sentence is *"Eddie smiled as Will talked with **him and his wife**"*.

Answer (score 1):

Your version is correct. My opinion is `talk` should be used with `to` unless the subject is not an expression.

> Eddie smiled as Will talked to him and his wife.
>
> Eddie smiled as Will talked with decency.

Answer (score 0):

> Eddie smiled as Will talked with *him* and his wife.

This is the correct version. Because without *and his wife* you would say

> Eddie smiled and talked with *him*.

As for *talk with* versus, *talk to* see [this question about the difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9044/what-is-the-difference-between-talk-to-and-talk-with) and [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3060).

Answer (score 0):

The correct standard English sentence is -

> Eddie smiled as Will talked with **him** and his wife.

The rule to use the correct case of pronoun in standard English is to substitute the whole coordination and replace it with a single pronoun. Now the case of the single pronoun is the case that we should use for the pronoun in coordination.

In the sentence below -

> <sub>**?**</sub> Eddie smiled as Will talked with he and his wife.

The coordination - *he and his wife*. 
We have to determine the case of the pronoun **he**. So we have to replace the whole coordination with a single pronoun, say *them* here.

> Eddie smiled as Will talked with **them**.

The pronoun - **them** - is in object form. So in coordination also we have to use the object form of pronoun. So the correct Standard English sentence is -

> Eddie smiled as Will talked with **him** and his wife.

---

**Aside**

But the sentence you quoted is not considered ungrammatical, at least to some variant of English. And maybe that is the reason it appeared in a newspaper article, though, I believe, it's recommended to follow correct standard English in newspaper articles, not regional English.

> <sub>**%**</sub> Eddie smiled as Will talked with **he** and his wife.

There are many instances of such sentence. Though the most common of them is the coordination where the pronoun (especially **"I"**) is after the coordinator, and its case is subject case.

> <sub>**%**</sub> The present was supposed to represent Helen and **I**, that was the problem.
>
> <sub>**%**</sub> It would be an opportunity from you and **I** to spend some time together.

Though they are considered hypercorrection, the use of coordination with **"I"** as final coordinator is so common in speech and used by so broad a range of speakers that it has to be recognised as a variety of Standard English.

% -> Grammatical in some dialects only

<sub>Reference - Cambridge Grammar of English Language</sub>